# Rcharts rPlot - R statistics

Tags: axis, rcharts

I want to use this command

```
r1 <- rPlot(y~x, color="z", data=my_df, type="tile")
```

It works, but I want the labels in the X-AXE to be perpendicular to the x-axe.
I can't find any material on the web about this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about rPlot but when using plot() you can rotate them using las=.

Example:

```
r1 <- plot(x, y, main = "title", col = "blue", las=1)
```